# How to handle Input Box Prompt Cancel Operation

Tags: excel, vba

Hy, I am using an input box for copy range from one sheet and paste it to another sheet. I got an error when I press the cancel button on the prompt for range selection. the error was Error Code 424 "Object Required". So I want to handle this error with message box "You did not select the copy range." I have tried it in different ways but could not get the final solution. Below are[image] my code and error message.

```
Sub ImportDatafromotherworksheet()
    Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
    Dim rngSourceRange As Range
    Dim rngDestination As Range
    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.count > 0 Then
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
            Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
            Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select All Data You Want to Copy.", Title:="Select All Data", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
            
            On Error GoTo 0
            If rngSourceRange Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
            End If
            
            wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
            Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:="Select Destination", Default:="A2", Type:=8)
            rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination
            rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            wkbSourceBook.Close False
           
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

So the above error appeared when I do the following work.
[image]

When I click the cancel button without a selection of any range, the above error message appears. How to resolve this issue, guide me, please. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press cancel the `InputBox` returns a boolean `False`.
But only objects can use `Set` and a boolean is no obejct. Therefore you need an `On Error Resume Next` to turn error reporting off.

```
On Error Resume Next 'turns error reporting off until GoTo 0
Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select All Data You Want to Copy.", Title:="Select All Data", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0 'turns error reporting on again.
```

Now `rngSourceRange` will be `Nothing` if you pressed cancel.